# Fetching data from websites and make them into .txts

Tags: c

I am having an assignment in which I have to fetch data from a site (somewhat like a news site) and make them into text files and then list them using tags.
Could someone please provide me some information/knowledge/keywords/instructions that can help me finish this?(using C only) Thank you.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: windows 8.1 @szczurcio :D

Comment: It's too broad a question to answer. I'm not knowledgeable, but there may be 1000 ways to do so....

Comment: @NatashaDutta then please pick a fairly easy way and give me some instruction/ keywords

Comment: I would have done that gladly, if you would have tried something of yourself first. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept is this: you'll need to connect to the HTTP server on port 80, fetch the HTML, parse it and store the information you want in files. To accomplish the former, if you're using Windows, you can use the [`WinInet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. Otherwise go with `cURL`, which is a very popular, efficient, cross-platform solution.

The other tasks require a relatively good command of C, but it's nothing special - you'll need to work with strings to parse your results, then use C's file I/O (`fopen`/`fprintf`/`fwrite`) to save your stuff to disk.